# How to collect iterators from a vector of data structures

Tags: c++, iterator

I'm looking for some help with a function i'm trying to write. 
The purpose is to get all the iterators for various data structures  which have been loaded into a vector.

For example:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<XXXX<std::string>>>
```

Where XXXX  is the structure to get the iterators for.

real examples

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::multiset<std::string>>>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<custom_list<std::string>>>
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<custom_tree<std::string>>>
```

*edited: removed typo*

Below is the code I've currently written, but its very convoluted and also doesn't compile correctly

```
template <typename L, typename V>
bool get_iterators(L to_sort, V all_iterator)
{
    for (auto &&pointer : *(to_sort))
    {   
        if (typeid(pointer) == typeid
(std::unique_ptr<std::multiset<std::string>>))
        {
            all_iterator->push_back(pointer->begin());
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

and

```
template <typename T>
void merge_sort(T &to_sort)
{
    if (typeid(to_sort) == typeid(std::vector<std::unique_ptr<std::multiset<std::string>>>))
    {
        std::vector<std::multiset<std::string>::iterator> all_iterator;
        get_iterators(&to_sort, &all_iterator);


    }
    else
    {
       ...
    }
}
```

The extended code would also do the

```
if (typeid(pointer) == typeid(std::unique_ptr<std::XXXX<std::string>>))
```

which seems very unnecessary. Also when I add these extra checks I get compile errors saying no valid function is found.

As above the purpose is to get all the iterators for various data structures.

Comment: Irrelevant, but do you really want to place `custom_list` or `custom_tree` in `std`? ;-)

Comment: @L.F. No you're right. That is a typo

Comment: It seems it's better to use `if constexpr (is_same_v<T, std::vector<...>>)` instead of `if (typeid(...) == typeid(...))`, so you won't get compile errors when doing some stuff with things, which have properties specific for concrete type

Comment: @J.S. thanks. I'll look into that

Comment: Isn’t the point of having all containers provide `begin` and `end` that you can simply write templates and never mention which type happens to be in use?

Comment: @DavisHerring I would believe so. Yes. I don't know how to do it correctly

Answer (score 0):

Here’s the trivial template answer:

```
template<class V>
auto get_iterators(V &v) {
  std::vector<decltype(v.front()->begin())> ret;
  for(auto &u : v)
    ret.push_back(u->begin());
  return ret;
}
```

By returning by value, the client is simplified:

```
auto iters=get_iterators(to_sort);
```

which easily avoids repeating the actual algorithm using the iterators.